# what does roi_gray function do in opencv

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a face detection program and I don't understand the following functions:

```
roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

Comment: roi stands for region of interest; other than that I don't know what could be unclear...

Comment: And it's not a function, nor related to opencv. It's simply numpy slicing

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned by @Berriel & @Miki in the comments. ROI stands for region of intrest.

```
roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

This slices the gray array. It basically selects row starting with `y` till `y+h` & column starting with `x` till `x+w`. This works the same way with `roi_color`.

So essentially you are selecting height of gray pixels starting up from `y` and going till `y+h` (as h denotes height). And selecting width staring from `x` pixel and going till `x+w` pixels (w denotes width here).

I hope this helps !
Here is the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_of_interest) link for `roi`

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the co-ordinates of face by writing

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    roi_gray=gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]    #This particular code will return the cropped face from the image.
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] #This particular code will return the details of the image that u will recive after getting the co-ordinates of the image.
```